# What is the meaning of "make of" in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

"Normans' ambition was to make of England a trilingual country."

What is the meaning of phrasal verb "make of."

Comment: Maybe, it could be paraphrased as "Normans' ambition was to make  a trilingual country of England."

Comment: What @dan said. Including optional ***of*** in such constructions today would normally be seen as dated / poetic / pompous / stilted.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean, "**the** Normans".

This is an inversion. The standard version would be:

"The Normans' ambition was to make a trilingual country of England."

This can be compared with, "Janet's ambition was to make a teapot of clay."

So Janet wishes to convert clay into a teapot. The Normans want to convert England into a tri-lingual nation.